# How to resolve this error - Value of property {/DistributionConfig/Aliases} does not match type {Array}

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I am getting this error while creating a distribution

[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCwgv.png)

this is my code

[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXJy9.png)

Comment: What are you actually running? If you are clicking buttons in the AWS Console, then specify what buttons you pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `"Aliases"` needs to be an array, but you provide an object. Try to change `{` and `}` to `[` and `]` like this:

```
"Aliases": [
    ... 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to keep the Aliases in array

```
                    "DefaultRootObject" : "index.html",
                    "Aliases" : [
                                "Fn::Join": [
                                    "", [
                                        "fastlanedocs",
                                        {
                                            "Ref": "EnvironmentName"
                                        },
                                        ".wm.com"
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ],
                    "DefaultCacheBehavior" : {
```